# Nextjs build phase in docker using CSR

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, dockerfile

When i try to build nextjs in using doker, I get the error "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND server", where server is another run container.
As I understood it's because of no access to server container in building image phase for nextjs
I checked after a build image was done and run I can have access to server host inside another running container.
Also I tryed to use curl in nextjs Dockerfile to check if i can have access to my server host but I didn't have
I tried to use links, networks in docker-compose, the same issue

[dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JZkr.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSdg5.png)

[docker-compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fKtH.png)